# Law of Probability question

Tags: probability

Question: 40% of Vancouverites are avid skiiers, whereas only 20% of people living in Canada are avid skiiers. Vancouverites make up about 2% of the population of Canada. You know that Johann lives in Canada, but you’re not sure where. Given that Johann is an avid skier, what is the probability that he lives in Vancouver?

I need help with this question and your help will be greatly appreciated if you can show me how to set it up and calculate the probability

so Far I set it up as:

A-> Vancouverites are avid skiers (4/10)

b-> People living in Canada are avid skiers (2/10)

c-> Vancouverites make up Canada's pop (0.2/10)

Comment: Have you heard of conditional probability?  How about Bayes' Theorem?

Comment: Yeah but i'm having trouble setting it up

Comment: Let $S$ be the event that a randomly selected canadian is an avid skiier.  Let $V$ be the event that a randomly selected canadian lives in Vancouver.  You are told $Pr(S),Pr(V)$ and $Pr(S\mid V)$.  Can you match your probabilities that you wrote down so far in your setup to these expressions?  Now... you are tasked with calculating $Pr(V\mid S)$.  Can you remember the statement of Bayes' Theorem and find an expression for $Pr(V\mid S)$ which involves the values $Pr(V),Pr(S),Pr(S\mid V)$ which we were told in the problem statement?

Comment: honestly im really confused, so would it be Pr(V|S)= (Pr(S|V)*Pr(S) / (not sure) and what happens to the event a, do we not need that number?

Comment: $Pr(A\mid B)=\dfrac{Pr(B\mid A)Pr(A)}{Pr(B)}$.  Now... if we use $V$'s and $S$'s instead of $A$'s and $B$'s... and if we plug in the appropriate numbers...

Comment: okay so I got Pr(V | S) = Pr(S | V) Pr(V) / Pr(S) = (4/10)(0.2/10) / ((2/10) is this correct or i'm wrong?

Comment: That is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(0.4)(0.02) = 0.008$

$\frac{0.008}{0.2} = 0.04$

Because 0.8% of the Canadian skiers are Vancouverites. If your a skier in Canada there's a 4% chance that your a vancouverite as 20% of Canadians are skiers.

Answer (score -1):

I could be wrong but for the Pr(S) = Pr(S|V)*Pr(V) + Pr(S/C)*Pr(~V)

making (
Pr(V|S)= Pr(V)*Pr(S|V) )/ ( Pr(S|V)*Pr(V) + Pr(S/C)*Pr(~V))

( (0.02)(0.4) ) / ( (0.02)(0.4)+(0.2)(0.98)

=0.039